# trouble in calculation the right algorithm in javascript to draw an array

Tags: javascript

this is my jsbin : http://jsbin.com/mipazizakafe/1/edit

what i am trying to do is drawing this image inside my div

[image]

the code :

```
function loademoji(RowCount,ColumnCount){
 var toAppend = "<div class='emojiContainer_div'><table  width='100%'>";
  for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
    toAppend += "<tr>";
    for (j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++) {
        toAppend += "<td><div class='emojiIcon' style='background-position:" + RowCount + "px " + ColumnCount * i + "px;' ></div></td>";
    }
    toAppend += "</tr>";
}
toAppend += "</table></div>";
return toAppend;
```

}
`RowCount` is the number of row to be drawn ,`ColumnCount` is the number of column to be drawn ,
I am having some trouble to draw the images as you can see ,can anyone help me to fix my algorithm

Comment: Where's the problem? It draws two rows and 16 columns as it should.

Comment: but it's not drawing the right images :) my main problem is calculating the exact `background-position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version: http://jsbin.com/tepocevakolo/3/edit

You need *negative* background positions to shift down/right.

```
function loademoji(RowCount,ColumnCount){
   var toAppend = "<div class='emojiContainer_div'><table  width='100%'>";
    for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
        toAppend += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++) {
            toAppend += "<td><div class='emojiIcon' style='background-position: -" + j*17 + "px -" + i*17 + "px;' ></div></td>";
        }
        toAppend += "</tr>";
    }
    toAppend += "</table></div>";
    return toAppend;

}
```

EDIT (changed 19 -> 17). Also note the CSS is slightly modified `width:17px; height:17px;`

Comment: thank you for your solution this is exactly what i need but can u explain why you used 17 and 19 ?

Comment: That's the height and width of each of the icons in the grid.

Comment: Although on closer inspection I think they are actually 17px square. http://jsbin.com/tepocevakolo/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Your logic to change the background position was somehow odd, the correct code must be like this:

```
function loademoji(RowCount,ColumnCount){
   var size = 17;
   var toAppend = "<div class='emojiContainer_div'><table  width='100%'>";
    for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
        toAppend += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++) {
          toAppend += "<td><div class='emojiIcon' style='background-position:" + (i * size) + "px " + (j * size) + "px;' ></div></td>";
        }
        toAppend += "</tr>";
    }
    toAppend += "</table></div>";
    return toAppend;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nunimoqucoje/1/edit

Comment: it's not drawing the same images , I mean you can see that the second image for example in your code it's the same as the second image in the `emoji image`

Comment: @Sora okay, what were you trying to reach?

Comment: i want to draw the exact same images in their correct positions check @RobH solution